# Rails associated model from arrays of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` model which has many `Contact` and `Contact` belongs to `User`. I am trying to retrieve `contacts` of selected user, which can be done by following:

```
id = [1,2,3,4,5]
users = User.includes(:contacts).find(id)

contacts = []

users.each do |user|
  contacts << user.contacts.as_json
end

render json: contacts
```

Is there any better way to get `contacts` from `users` arrays. Secondly, how to only load contacts by left joining on user ids and not the entire users columns to save memory usage, (other than `#select(:id)` approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the `contacts` and `render` it, as you have no use of `User` why not:

```
contacts = Contact.where(user_id: user_ids)
```

Where `user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: 31 fewer characters. Clean. No extra json rendering. Good stuff!

Answer (score 3):

You could get all the users passing the array of ids, as:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
users = User.includes(:contacts).where(users: { id: ids })
```

But if you only want the contacts then you can query the contact table, using the relationship with the user table, and also passing the array of ids, like

```
Contact.joins(:user).where(users: { id: [1,2,3,4,5] })
```

And then to get its json format, then use `as_json`, so:

```
@contacts = Contact.joins(:user).where(users: { id: [1,2,3,4,5] }).as_json
render json: @contacts
```

Comment: I think using as_json is better than using to_json.

Comment: I was searching for a way to query a model based upon an array of related model IDs and your second example was a life-saver. Thanks!